# Maya referenceQuery namespace bug

Tags: python, maya

I'm trying to get a reference's namespace with this command:

`cmds.referenceQuery(filePath, namespace=True)`

This works as expected on loaded and unloaded references. I noticed I get an error if I try this with a reference that has never been loaded before. But if I load it then unload it, it works. Is this a bug? How can I get its namespace without getting this error?

The error it throws is as follows:

```
# Error: RuntimeError: file <maya console> line 1: Cannot find the associated namespace. #
```

Edit:

Just noticed that the namespace doesn't actually exist in the namespace editor until the reference is loaded. Still, is there some way to get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found I can get its namespace this way.

```
cmds.file(filePath, q = True, namespace = True)
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work in maya 2020

Answer (score 0):

Building on the other answer, here's a more complete solution that should handle all ref nodes:

```
def getRefNamespace(refNode):
    try:
        if mc.referenceQuery(refNode, isLoaded=True):
            return mc.referenceQuery(refNode, namespace=True).lstrip(':')
        return mc.file(mc.referenceQuery(refNode, filename=True), query=True, namespace=True)
    except RuntimeError:
        return None
```

It's possible to have references without an associated file, so it's only using the filename check as a fallback.